# How to check if every checkbox in different tabs are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, logic

I'm working on a project with Java as the backend tech, JSPs and JS with jQuery on the frontend. I'm new to JS and jQuery or at least I'm no pro so I'm trying to do my best here.

So the thing is: I have this screen I'm working on, it shows two users or more and some information related to them. Each user (and its information) is on a different tab. Each user/tab has a checkbox that MUST be checked in order to go to the next screen. So if we have two users, both checkboxes MUST be checked. If we have five, all five of them. The screen is something like this (keeping in mind that the pink one is the selected user):

[image: The screen]

So the thing is, sometimes, my logic works well and I can move on to the next screen after checking all the checkboxes. But other times after refreshing the page, as I discovered using some `console.log`s, the checkbox on the first user is executing the code for all the checkboxes while the rest of the checkboxes are not doing anything. So I can't go on to the next screen unless I check the box in all the users and the first one last. The same happens if I uncheck a checkbox on the second user, it's not doing anything because its code is not executing.

I have a JS function on change that checks if all the checkboxes are checked in order to show the arrow to the next screen. Like this:

```javascript
$("#demPricesCheckbox").change(function () {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("[id='demPricesCheckbox']");
  var show = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length && show; i++) {
    if (!checkboxes[i].checked) show = false;
  }
  if (show) {
    ContractPrices.showForwardButton();
  } else {
    ContractPrices.hideForwardButton();
  }
});
```

And my checkbox HTML reads as follows:

```html
<label class="sub-checkbox" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 5px">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="demPricesCheckbox"
    name="demPricesCheckbox"
    value="1"
  />
  <branches:message code="NAME_OF_CHECKBOX" />
</label>
```

Any hints? I would appreciate any ideas or explanations on why this could be happening. If you need more info just ask me.

Thank you for your time! And pardon my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is close, but there are a few things to keep in mind.

- HTML elements should have *unique* `id` attributes, meaning that you should never have more than 1 element with the same `id` on any page.
- You should check the "state" of your user interface on every interaction – this is the foundation of reactive programming, and something that jQuery/React/Vue makes easy.

I've written and annotated some code that should help clarify.

```js
// You have jQuery installed, so let's use that instead of vanilla
// This is a CSS selector for "all checkboxes in the DOM".
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(() => {
  // Count how many checkboxes you have on the page
  // You can use a different method
  const totalNumberOfCheckboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']").length;

  let countChecked = 0;

  // Now, let's loop through them all and see if they are all checked
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each((index, element) => {
    // Increase the counter only if the checkbox is checked
    if (element.checked) {
      countChecked += 1;
    }
  });

  // Now, let's check if they are all checked!
  if (totalNumberOfCheckboxes === countChecked) {
    // Enable your button
    console.log("Enabling the next button");
    $(".btn.next").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    // Disable the button
    console.log("Disabling the next button because all the checkboxes are not checked.");
    $(".btn.next").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});

// Next button click listener
// This will only trigger when clicked, and the button is "enabled" – i.e.: not "disabled"
$(".btn.next").click(() => {
  console.log('Go to the next page :)')
  
  // This is just for the example – it disables all the checkboxes again
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each((index, element) => {
    element.checked = false;
  });
});

// Setup
// This is not waiting for events, so it will run
// when the page is loaded
console.log("Disabling the next button because the page has just been loaded");
$(".btn.next").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <input id="user1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="user1">User 1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="user2" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="user2">User 2</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="user3" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="user3">User 3</label>
</div>

<button class="btn next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it was useful. The thing I don't get is the following: how can I "generate" unique ids for the checkboxes if I don't know before hand how many users will be on screen? I mean, they come from database so there could be one or ten, and the JSP code with the checkbox is the same for everyone. Also, what would happen if there were more than those checkbox on the screen, for example a kind of checkbox that is not mandatory to check because it does other kind of stuff? So the mandatory but also the one which is just for other purposes. Thank you!